# Adding a line into the hosts file, getting permission denied when using sudo - Mac

Tags: linux, macos, sudo, hosts

I'm trying to add a line into the hosts file on my Mac by executing a one line command on the terminal.

I thought this would be easy using sudo, but it returns "permission denied" when I try to add `>>` to the hosts file, but it works if I try replace `>` the hosts contents.

```
sudo echo test >> /etc/hosts
-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
$

sudo echo test > /etc/hosts
Password:
$
```

OS is up to date.

Comment: simply use a text editor (started with *sudo*) to modify your */etc/hosts*

Comment: I want to make a script that will help automate this, so a text editor wouldn't help in this case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's because `echo` is being run as root, but the shell is the one actually performing the redirection. You need to spawn a new shell for this to work:

```
sudo -- sh -c "echo test >> /etc/hosts"
```

Edit: I haven't seen the fact that the `>` redirect works; I can't explain that.

Comment: I feel it's worth noting the utility `tee` because allowing a subshell execution from `sudo` is and should be blocked in most production environments for security reasons.

Answer (score 17):

Rather then running echo through a redirect which will be run as your current user, not root as echo is being run in your example, use [tee](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tee.1.html) as Steve Buzonas [suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/538760/adding-a-line-into-the-hosts-file-getting-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-m#comment-880944)

```
 echo 'test' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

The sudo is now applied to the tee command. The '-a' appends to the file

This will also output tee to standard output. If you don't want to see 'test' in your terminal also add: `> /dev/null` to the end of that line.

Answer (score 3):

Works also well from a script:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "127.0.0.1 mydomain" >> /etc/hosts'
```

Comment: I like this because it matches our crontab scripting style.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that a new line was created first, I used this:

```
sudo -- sh -c "echo  \ \ >> /etc/hosts";sudo -- sh -c "echo 127.0.0.1  testdomain.com >> /etc/hosts"
```